# How to pop a div by onclicking the another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this `div` tag which contains a Google visualization chart. What I want is to pop up that chart in a pop up box by `onclick`ing the chart (`div`).

I am using jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS

```
.model{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1000;
    top:20%;
    left:20%;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;

}
```

Jquery

```
$(".chartDiv").on("click", function () {
   var content = $(this).html();
    $('.model').show().html(content);


});
```

html

```
<div class="chartDiv">Chart 1</div>
<div class="chartDiv">Chart 2</div>
<div class="model"></div>
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tutspack/HDmVc/)

Answer (score 2):

Just grab the contents of the clicked div and copy it to another div that you then position properly.

```
$(".someChart").on("click", function() {
    // Fill popup with html
    $('.popupDiv').html($(this).html());
    // now show the popup and possibly position it correctly
    $('.popupDiv').show();
});
```

Comment: Glad I could help :-) If you're satisfied, you can accept an answer so that the question is marked as answered!